# How to list all controller class name in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create user authentication with access level for my site back end. I want get and list all controller class name for create user group creation.

**Thanks in advance,**

*Logan*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet for this is to explicitly write them into a new config file.

```
$config['controllers'] = array(
    'blog',
    'events',
    'news', // etc.
);
```

Otherwise, you will be scanning directories which will eat up resources. But you could do it like this:

```
    $controllers = array();
    $this->load->helper('file');

    // Scan files in the /application/controllers directory
    // Set the second param to TRUE or remove it if you 
    // don't have controllers in sub directories
    $files = get_dir_file_info(APPPATH.'controllers', FALSE);

    // Loop through file names removing .php extension
    foreach (array_keys($files) as $file)
    {
        $controllers[] = str_replace(EXT, '', $file);
    }
    print_r($controllers); // Array with all our controllers
```

Since file names match controller names, now you should have an array of all your controllers. This isn't perfect though for several reasons, but should work for most setups.

Personally I use a highly modified directory structure, so this wouldn't work for me, and some controllers I would want to ignore as well. Another option would be to cache the results to a file, but that's a separate tutorial.

I highly suggest defining them in a config file, this way you can store other useful information directly related to your access control and avoid the huge overhead of recursively scanning directories.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to you could possibly do this is by creating an interface that you can then check for within your authentication system, for example, create a class like so:

```
interface IAuthorizationRequired
{
     public function __auth();
}
```

Now create your controller (pseudo)

```
class BlogController extends CI_Controller implements IAuthorizationRequired
{
     public function __auth()
     {
          /*Redirect or Custom*/
     }
}
```

and within your authorization module, you load the current controller and do the follewing:

```
if(($controller instanceof IAuthorizationRequired) && method_exists(array($controller,'__auth')))
{
     $authed = $controller->__auth();
     if(!$authed)
     {
         echo 'Authorization Failed';
         exit;
     }
}
```

Within 2.0 you can override the base controller and add you method __auth to that, and then just check the interface, and  run the auth.