# CodeIgniter - How to check if a word is a controller name in my project or not?

Tags: codeigniter, security, authentication

I have defined an encryption method for back reference of my login page in CodeIgniter. My encrypted string is a controller name which user was calling login function from that.

It's working fine but there is a security risk if I redirect to invalid decoded addresses before checking decoded strings is valid controller or not.

For example after a successful login to a link like `http://example.com/login/sH-hs-eY-Tz` it will redirect me back to `http://example.com/home/` which `home` is decoded version of `sH-hs-eY-Tz` and everything is ok till now.
Now if a user try to login from some other url like `http://example.com/login/gh-Yh-LJ-gh` (s)he will be redirected to some url like `http://example.com/decode(gh-Yh-LJ-gh)/` which is letting him/she to access my decryption method in url and showing a simple 404 page not found output. So this should be a security risk if I not check decoded string to be a valid controller name before applying a redirection to it.

So I only want a method to dynamically **check if a string for example "Home" or "test" or "Welcome" is a controller name in my project or not?** How can I handle this on a right way?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear..what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @IdentityUnkn0wn In mvc we have to define controllers to create diffrent outputs. So we always have at least one controller in each mvc application. For example when we setup CodeIgniter it have one controller named "welcome.php" which manages and controls default output. I can add as many controllers as I want or change any controllers. I want to know how can I dynamically have a list of my defined controllers in my project.

Comment: You can define your path to controllers based on URL by defining it in your routes.php file

Comment: @IdentityUnkn0wn But this is out of the question. I don't need to setup path, and there is no problem in routes or default route. I'm asking about having list of my controller names **dynamically** for example in a string variable or in an array() of strings.

Comment: @IdentityUnkn0wn I have edited question and added more descriptions as an example to clear what I really mean to do. I hope It will be helpful to be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `config` element array in your `config.php` file.

Create an array in that  file consisting of all the `encoded string` of your `controllers`. For Example

```
$config['encodedControllers'] => array(
                "sH-hs-eY-Tz",
                "iu-ss-et-az",
                "sH-vs-eY-fz",
                "gH-ns-bY-cz",
    );
```

Then from where ever you want to check just call this `array` using

```
$controllersArray = $this->config->item('encodedControllers');
```

Get the `uri` segment from the URL using

`$controllerName = $this->uri->segment(3); // NOTE the number inside segment() may differ according to your URL`

Check if this `$controllerName` exists in $controllersArray using `in_array()`,

```
if(in_array($controllersArray,$controllerName )){
   //Do the redirection
}
else{
  //Do what ever you want to
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really what I'm looking for. I wanted to dynamically access to list of existing controllers on my project.

Comment: please define "dynamicalyy access to list of existing controllers?"

Comment: I asked a new simpler question about this topic here and it is answered there before I answer your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723876. Thanks for your helps

Comment: instead of scanning the files, array method is more efficient

Comment: Although I did not see this link before , I got this link from the link that you provided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919546/how-to-list-all-controller-class-name-in-codeigniter

Comment: +1 I agree, it should be much faster, but I prefer to have a dynamic solution, rather than defining constants manually.