# CodeIgniter - How to get a list of all my controllers dynamically?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I need to run a function to do some actions with each controller-name on my project.
My function is defined on a controller like this:

```php
class Some_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function someActions(){
        // $listOfAllControllers = some_method_I_need_for_my_answer();
        foreach($listOfAllControllers as $controllerName){
            // some_action($controllerName)
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is **a dynamic list of all controllers which exists in my project**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919546/how-to-list-all-controller-class-name-in-codeigniter  have you checked this

Comment: [It](https://github.com/pprins/CI_ListControllers) isn't being modified for long time but worked very well i used last time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scan your `/application/controllers directory` and remove file extension from it

```php
    $controllers = array();
    $this->load->helper('file');

    // Scan files in the /application/controllers directory
    // Set the second param to TRUE or remove it if you 
    // don't have controllers in sub directories
    $files = get_dir_file_info(APPPATH.'controllers', FALSE);

    // Loop through file names removing .php extension
    foreach ( array_keys($files) as $file ) {
        if ( $file != 'index.html' )
            $controllers[] = str_replace('.php', '', $file);
    }
    print_r($controllers); // Array with all our controllers
```

OR

You can also follow this link to achieve this

[controller list](https://github.com/pprins/CI_ListControllers)

Comment: No credits to original poster !
Ah thats brutal. copy of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919546/how-to-list-all-controller-class-name-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Saty getting error like `Fatal error: Cannot declare class , because the name is already in use in` this library

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'controllers/*' . 'php') as $controller){
   $controller = basename($controller, '.php');
}
```