# How to get all controllers and methods in a array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to get all of the controllers and their methods in a single array.

For example, the following code in my `inventory` controller:

```
public function get_all_methods()
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(get_class_methods($this));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Gives this output:

```
Array
(
      [0] => __construct
      [1] => index
      [2] => add_product
      [3] => edit_product
      [4] => delete_product
)
```

But i want something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Inventory] => Array
        (
            [0] => __construct
            [1] => index
            [2] => add_product
            [3] => edit_product
            [4] => delete_product
        )
    [Invoice] => Array
        (
            [0] => __construct
            [1] => index
            [2] => create_invoice
            [3] => invoice_list
        )
)
```

And how can i remove some known methods like `__construct` and `index` from the output array?

Comment: create your custom core controller extend your current controller with custom core and call print_r(get_class_methods($this)); in custom core

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177864/get-all-functions-name-from-all-controllers-in-codeigniter, duplicate

Comment: That's great :) . Where i should modify to remove the known methods like `__construct` and `index` ?

Comment: You can delete/unset array items: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array